# html select установить значение

Tags: javascript, html

Есть простая select форма

```
{% for select_data in input_form %}
<select>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>22</option>
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

Как я могу не используя метод "selected" установить значение в форму с сервера?
Условно, чтобы это выглядело как-то так(знаю что value нет у select)

```
{% for select_data in input_form %}
<select value="{{ select_data }}">
    <option>11</option>
    <option>22</option>
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

Либо может есть js скрипт, куда бы я передал значение {{ select_data }}, а он бы подставил в option с таким же названием значение `<option selected>`

Comment: Вот скрипт `document.querySelector('select').value = 11`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @ksa, понял как сделать

```
<script>
   {% for select_data in input_form %}
        document.querySelector('select').value = '{{ select_data }}';
   {% endfor %}
</script>
```